# how to do source code coverage of gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

For a given sample program I want to know which part of GCC's source code is used during compilation.

**BUILDING GCC**:
I tried building gcc-8.2 source code using

```
./src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++
    --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib BOOT_CFLAGS="-O2 -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs"
```

I have a sample program named program.c

I am compiling the program.c with xgcc as

```
/path/to/xgcc -B path/to/stage1build/gcc -ftest-coverage program.c
```

The above command gives me code coverage of program .The problem is I don't want to find code coverage of program.c using gcov and lcov.

I want to find code coverage of gcc's source code.

I tried searching on web but almost all of the answers tell me how do I use gcov and lcov by giving example of a sample .c program .

**NOTE:**
I know how to use gcov and lcov

Comment: Maybe try using the `-ftest-coverage` flag when you build gcc rather than when you compile your program? -- Edit -- I am not a gcc expert, just making an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

As per searching online for the `BOOT_CFLAGS`, it seems it sets the default compiler flags for the code that you would be compiling.
Refer here:[1](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTEzOTA), [2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49275)

Probably you need to run configure something like this:

```
./src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib CFLAGS="-O2 -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs"
```

But you might face other issues while building with coverage enabled [GCC Build with coverage](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-04/msg00222.html).

Better would be to post on GCC mailing list to see if someone has a probable solution.